# How to create a zip with multiple files without sub-folders?

Tags: command-line, zip

**Initial situation:**

```
.
├── d0
├── f0
├── f1
│   └── d1
└── f2
    └── f3
        ├── d2
        ├── d3
        └── d4
```

**What I need to do:**

I would like to create a zip containing d0, d1 and d4 which must have the fallowing structure:

```
.
├── d0
├── d1
└── d4
```

**What I have already tried:**

I tried it with `zip myfiles d0 f1/d1 f2/f3/d4`. But this keeps the original folder structure, which is not what I want.

```
.
├── d0
├── f1
│   └── d1
└── f2
    └── f3
        └── d4
```

**Question**
How to create a zip with multiple files without the sub-folders?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Manually, you can create the zip file and the update it:

```
zip myfiles d0
(cd f1; zip -u ../myfiles.zip d1)
(cd f2/f3; zip -u ../../myfiles.zip d4)
```

The parentheses create subshells, and the effect of the `cd` only lasts in the subshell, so you don't have to `cd` back to the original directory.

If `d1`, `d2`, etc. are actually files and not directories themselves, then use the `-j` option:

> **-j**
>   **--junk-paths**
>   Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store
>   directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to
>   the current directory).

Answer (score 21):

You can use `find` to get the file list and execute `zip -j myfiles` to pack them ignoring the paths:

```
find . -name "d[014]" -exec zip -j myfiles {} +
```

#### Example

```
$ tree
.
├── d0
├── f0
├── f1
│   └── d1
└── f2
    └── f3
        ├── d2
        ├── d3
        └── d4

$ find . -name "d[014]" -exec zip -j myfiles {} +
  adding: d1 (stored 0%)
  adding: d4 (stored 0%)
  adding: d0 (stored 0%)

$ unzip -l myfiles.zip
Archive:  myfiles.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-10-09 10:47   d1
        0  2017-10-09 10:48   d4
        0  2017-10-09 10:47   d0
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

However this **works for files only**, directories will be ignored by `zip -j`. To get this working for directories too, say we want to pack `d0`, `d1` and the whole `f3` directory in the above example, the `find` line gets a little more complicated:

```
$ find . \( -name "d[01]" -o -name "f3" \) -exec sh -c 'p=$(pwd); for i in $0 $@; do cd ${i%/*}; zip -ur "$p"/myfiles ${i##*/}; cd "$p"; done' {} +
        zip warning: /home/dessert/myfiles.zip not found or empty
  adding: d1 (stored 0%)
  adding: f3/ (stored 0%)
  adding: f3/d3 (stored 0%)
  adding: f3/d2 (stored 0%)
  adding: f3/d4 (stored 0%)
  adding: d0 (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l myfiles.zip 
Archive:  myfiles.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-10-11 10:18   d1
        0  2017-10-11 10:19   f3/
        0  2017-10-11 10:19   f3/d3
        0  2017-10-11 10:19   f3/d2
        0  2017-10-11 10:19   f3/d4
        0  2017-10-11 10:17   d0
---------                     -------
        0                     6 files
```

Answer (score 18):

Using the -j option will remove the path from the file.

```
zip -j myfiles d0 f1/d1 f2/f3/d4
```

[reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

Comment: if any of the paths you are passing are not files but are directories, those directories will not be added to the `zip` file with the `-j` option.

Comment: @dan --if you want all the files in a directory with out the path then `zip -j myfiles directory/*`